# Opera reset extensions from the command line?

Tags: browser, opera

I have installed a dodgy extension on opera that keeps freezing it when opera starts. Is there a way to reset all extensions without loosing other data such as saved passwords or history.

There is the `--disable-extensions` option but this doesn't remove the extension, it only temporarily removes it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I found a solution:

I typed:
`rm -r ~/.config/opera/Extensions/*`

This deletes ALL extensions and opera is then restored beause the dodgy extension is removed, passwords and history are all still there.

Thanks to Matt832 for mentioning the opera installation location here:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=238442